# Validating string format using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

Check if the string is following the correct format or not. The correct format is as follows:

2 upper case letters; 2 digits; 1 to 30 characters alpha-numerical (case insensitive)
e.g. GB29RBOS60161331926819, 
     GB29RBOS60161331926819A, 
     GB29RBOS60161331926819B1

So far this is what i have got...

```
declare @accountNumber varchar(1000) = 'GB99AERF12FDG8AERF12FDG8AERF12FDG8'

select 
case when @accountNumber not like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]{30}$' 
then 'ERROR' else null end
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to validate IBAN numbers. You should do that in application layer, it's easier to implement [all checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Validating_the_IBAN) there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your structure assumes a case sensitive collation.  Second, SQL Server doesn't recognize `{}` or `$`, so you have to repeat the pattern.  However, you want up to 30 characters, so splitting the pieces apart is probably the best solution:

```
select (case when len(@accountNumber) not between 5 and 34 or
                  @accountNumber not like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]%' or
                  right(@accountNumber, 34) like '%[^A-Za-z0-9]%'
             then 'ERROR' 
        end)
```

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work... taking some tips from [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570000/john-cappelletti).

```
declare @table table (i varchar(36))
insert into @table
values
('GR09xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),     --30 x's
('GR09xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),       --28 x's
('GR09xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),    --31 x's
('Gx09xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),    --lower case 2'd letter
('G509xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),    --digit second letter
('GRg9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')     --charcater first number (3rd index)

select 
case 
    when i + replicate('a',case when 34-len(i) < 0 then 0 else 34-len(i) end) not like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]' + replicate('[a-zA-Z0-9]',30)
then 'ERROR' else null end
from @table
```

Comment: You "thunk" it better than I did.  +1

Comment: HAHA, I thought it was a clever idea from you